# Do I have to use URI redirect (DNS) for openshift custom domain setting?

Tags: redirect, seo, openshift, cname

Many articles says that the best practice for setting up DNS for customized domain on openshift is following:

@ -> http://domain.com  (301 URI redirect)

www -> openshift domain (CNAME)

Can I just change both to openshift domain?

@->openshift domain

www->openshift domain

Is 301 URI redirect is very important to SEO?

Answer (score 0):

@ usually will not accept a domain name, it has to be an ip address, so on most dns hosting services that won't work, which is why people do the redirect to the www that you can setup as a cname.

Comment: can I use both CNAME? That is, domain.com and www.domain.com all with CNAME records?